# How can I get to know which anchor tag got clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating my content dynamically, When a anchor tag is clicked `navigate()` function is called. How can i determine which **anchor** tag was clicked?

```
    function navigate()
    {
        //var location=$(this).attr("id");
        switch(location)
        {
            /*case "Configuration":     $('#detailTable').empty();
                                    $('#detailTable').append(navigateConfig);
            break;*/

            default: alert(location+" a tag was clicked");
        }
    }

    $('#detailTable').empty();
    $('<div width="100%">')
    .attr('id','javainfoSpan')
    .html('<div class="titleBlue"><a href="javascript:navigate();">Configuration</a>&gt;'+productname+'&gt;Java Properties</div>'+
            //some other stuff
        '</div>')       
    .appendTo('#detailTable');
```

**Update:**

My question is simple

1. there will be a number of `a` elements inside `detailTable`.
2. how can I get to know in some js function, which `a` element was clicked?

Comment: @Thomas: I am using a `anchor tag` nowhere there is a click event.. so that is why i asked how can i catch which `a` element is clicked?

Comment: Sorry, I saw what you're up to after posting the comment, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see what you're doing now, you're creating the `a` elements on the fly. If you call `javascript:navigate()` then you're using standard javascript, and not jquery (jquery is required to use the `$(this)` selector).

Instead you should have this:

```
$("body").on('click', 'a', function() {
  var location = $(this).attr('id');
  switch(location){ /* ... */ }
});
```

This will catch the click event in jquery for any a element that you either create on the fly or that's already there when the page loads.

Remember, if you're using `id` then you need to set the `id` attr on the `a` element.

Comment: That's fine, the only problem with that is when you come to change the text (which you may do in the future) you'll have to change every other mention in the code where you've referenced it. If you use the `id` then this will identify the `a` even when you change the text. Possibly just as usefully you can attach a `rel` attribute to `a` tags, or just use the `href` to add an identifier to the element.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function navigate($element) {
    //var location = $element.attr("id");   
    switch (location) {
        /*case "Configuration":     $('#detailTable').empty();
            $('#detailTable').append(navigateConfig);
            break;*/

        default: alert(location+" a tag was clicked");
    }
}

$('#detailTable').empty();
$('<div width="100%">')
    .attr('id','javainfoSpan')
    .html('<div class="titleBlue"><a href="#">Configuration</a>&gt;'+productname+'&gt;Java Properties</div>'+
        //some other stuff
        '</div>')       
    .appendTo('#detailTable');

// Pre jQuery 1.7...
$(".titleBlue").delegate("A", "click", function() {
    navigate($(this));
}

// jQuery 1.7...
$(".titleBlue A").on("click", function() {
    navigate($(this));
}
```

I changed the handler to use the `delegate()` method of jQuery (or the `on()` method for jQ 1.7+). Using this it makes it easier to pass the element which caused the event to your processing function, which it does as the `$element` variable.

You can then do with this as you need.

Comment: You shouldn't use `live()` it has been depreciated `As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().` (http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: Thanks for that. I've updated my post to cater for pre & post jQuery 1.7 versions

Comment: @Rory: It gives me "undefined"

Comment: @Abhishek That's because you meed to put your logic in to deal with the passed `$element`. Your OP didn't provide any information about this so I couldn't add it to my answer.

Comment: because the lines are commented out

Comment: @Thomas It's that, but there is also no `Id` attribute on the passed element to read.

Comment: @Rory: can you please take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400922/how-to-properly-place-jqgrid-inside-jpanel-and-jpanel-inside-jquery-ui-tabs)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to handle this too:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var productname = "mytest";
    $('#detailTable').empty();
    $('<div width="100%">').attr('id', 'javainfoSpan').html('<div class="titleBlue"><a href="#" id="'+productname+'" class="navigate">Configuration</a>&gt;' + productname + '&gt;Java Properties</div>' + '<table id="list1" width="100%"></table>' + '<div id="gridpager"></div>' + '</div>').appendTo('#detailTable');

    $(".navigate").click(function() {
        var location = $(this).attr("id");
        switch (location) {
        case "Configuration":
            $('#detailTable').empty();
            $('#detailTable').append(navigateConfig);
            break;
        case "mytest":
            alert("My test was clicked");
            break;
        default:
            alert(location + " a tag was clicked");
        }
    });
});
```

See it live on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6cggu/2/)

Answer (score 0):

you have to iterate through each element of  using jquery "each" function. By "this" you can get the click object.